# Cocoa NSOpenGLView - [win setDelegate:view ] shows error. How to delegate manually?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm programming in Eclipse (not Xcode) on Yosemita 10.10...
I try to catch MouseMoved event, but it not called (mouseDown, mouseDragged - works fine). So I'm using this example code from here
http://lists.apple.com/archives/mac-opengl/2003/Feb/msg00069.html
but compiller show error on
[app setDelegate: view];
(- cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id' with an lvalue of type 'NSView *')
If I comment this line - it's work, but mouseMoved don't calling.
Please help! I'm newbie in objective-c

Answer (score 0):

OS X does not automatically track the mouse movement events for you unless you request them.

In order to receive `mouseMoved:` events, you should add an `NSTrackingArea` to your subclass of `NSOpenGLView`. For example:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    NSTrackingArea *trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:self.frame options:NSTrackingActiveAlways|NSTrackingMouseMoved owner:self userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
}
```

After that, your `mouseMoved:` method will be called.

```
- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    NSLog(@"moved");
}
```

You can optionally implement `updateTrackingAreas` if you need to update your tracking area manually when the view resizes. For details, please refer to [Using Tracking-Area Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TrackingAreaObjects/TrackingAreaObjects.html).

Comment: Thank you very much!.. awakeFromNib doesn't called for mee, but I put this code to viewDidMoveToWindow and it's work fine now! <br> But keyDown event still dont't work.<br> I'm adds: <br> [win setInitialFirstResponder:view];<br>
  [win setNextResponder:view];<br>
  [win makeFirstResponder:view];<br>- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
return YES;//never called
}<br>And have no effect... Maybe I must to create NSController object subclass?(in wich case how can I connect this subclass to my NSView object?)

Comment: `keyDown:` is called on the first responder when you press a keyboard key. So make sure your `keyDown:` method is implemented in the right place. Also normally you do not need to manipulate the first responder as system will automatically set it based on user interaction.

Comment: Here is my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398605/cocoa-keydown-event-doesnt-call               Maybe it's not work because view have not delegate with win?